# how to suppress ld.so.preload error messages in gnome-terminal when I launch it

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, environment-variables

I built a 32 bit shared object and added its path to `/etc/ld.so.preload` to preload it  system wide. It works well and  all the applications in my system use it. But whenever I launch `gnome-terminal` I get an error message (though there is no problem) on top.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

How can I silence that error message in `gnome-terminal`?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to pinpoint and silence the error message. 
It is a warning message and causes no harm. 
When I search for that bugging message I noticed that it's a well-known issue with `Steam` since it uses 32 bit arch.

Some even proposed a [patch](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=159775&action=diff) to get rid of the message.

In my case it's triggered by environment variable sourced from my `~/.bashrc` which I added some time ago.

I found how to debug bash sourcing process in that link:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

At first I ran the following line in `gnome-terminal`

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2
```

It streams all the environment variable sourcing process.

Then I added the below line top of my `~/.bashrc`

```
 set -x
```

It shows the hidden process of sourcing `~/.bashrc`

The latter showed me  culprit line in my `~/.bashrc`

It was :

```
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

I silenced the error message with:

```
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
```